# How to know why is my Nook unable to boot into ClockWorkMod?

Tags: recovery-mode, boot, clockworkmod-recovery, nook-simple-touch

I have a Nook Simple Touch that is already rooted. I've used the Clockworkmod file that I downloaded from the XDA-developers website [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1360994).

These are the steps I followed:

1. I connected my device to my laptop with the micro-usb cable.
2. I had access to my SD card.
3. I opened the terminal window and entered this command.

   ```
   sudo dd if=2gb_clockwork-rc2.img  of=/dev/sdc
   ```
4. I rebooted into bootloader mode and it did not recognize clockworkmod.
5. I used adb commands to try to boot into the SD card. I was able to connect to my device but I was not able to get clockwork to load.
   I used these commands.

   ```
   adb reboot-bootloader
   adb reboot-recovery
   adb reboot recovery
   adb reboot bootloader|recovery
   ```

After more than five failed attempts I have preceded to this question.

Is this all because I was using the micro-usb cable to burn the .img file to the SD card instead of using a SD card writer?

If so how do I get it to boot into clockwork if the method of burning the image is the problem without getting an SD card reader.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the DD command to the SD card was probably a mistake. For Android using DD method usually is like **example only**:

1. Place `recovery.img` in the root of your `/sdcard` folder and rename it to `cwm.img`.
2. Run the following commands via ADB Shell or a terminal emulator app:

   ```
    su dd if=/sdcard/cwm.img of=/dev/block/platform/omap/omap_hsmmc.1/by-name/recovery
   ```

However, according to this guide, it will brick your device if you do it this way because the recovery is on the `/boot` partition. So not a good thing to try.

This guide was poorly written lacking detailed explanation. As far as the adb reboots stuff it looks like the developer could not get a handle on reboots so it's a bug.

The 2GB image can be used for installing ROMs and making backups. A 2GB image can be flashed on any sized SD card.

This is what I think you are trying to do. **Example of using 2GB image SD card method**:

1. Extract the `cwm.img` (if you can't open the file, use 7zip) and burn to SD card using win32diskimager (free) or winimage (shareware).

   For Linux, use [Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/). These apps will need to be "run as administrator". Some internal laptop/desktop readers will not work, so to do this, you may need an external USB reader if you run into problems.
2. Once the card is done, copy any ROMs, or ZIPs you want to flash over to the card (simple copy and paste job).
3. Turn your Nook off, insert the card and boot the nook. It should come up with CWM.

If you want to also replace the stock recovery with this developers CWM (personally I would not looks sketchy and cwm has been out of development for a very long time). It's a little unclear but from what I remember it goes like this. If an issue on this last part arise I will revise. I do not think one will though.

1. Copy this developers `install_cwm_recovery_xx.zip` from the downloads to the SD card (just a simple copy and paste job).
   2.Now, boot into CWM by placing your newly made SD card in the device and turning it on.
2. Go to and select the option *Use the install zip from sdcard* to install it (it just replaces uRecRam and URecImg in the `/boot` partition. You can also do this manually if you want).

Now you should have CWM permanently on the device if you so choose.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I was able to burn the image. I plan on installing CWM instead of using stock recovery on a rooted device is a bad idea from experience. It'll unroot it!! I need to re-install the su binaries!